# A statistics problem (normal distribution)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance

If $X\sim  N(0, \sigma^2)$, how can I compute $\operatorname{Var}(X^2)$? Here is my idea... but I cannot get there.
$$\operatorname{Var}(X^2) = E(X^4) - (E(X^2))^2$$

Comment: You get answers to these questions by a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but here's one. The moment-generating function of $X$ is $\exp\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}$. Its power series begins $1+\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}+\frac{\sigma^4t^4}{8}$. Multiplying the $t^4$ coefficient by $4!$ gives $E(X^4)=3\sigma^4$. I assume you know $E(X^2)=\sigma^2$, so the result is $2\sigma^4$.

Comment: Ohhhh. I see. I forgot the MGF... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2}dx=2\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2^{n-1/2}t^{n-1/2}e^{-t}dx=2^{n+1/2}\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right).$$